# Raspbian Jessie Lite Boot time fast?

Tags: raspbian, boot

How many seconds does it take to boot [Raspbian Jessie Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)? I have searched for previous user clocked speeds but could not find any.

I just ordered my first Raspberry Pi Zero and a Kingston 8GB Class 10 UHS-1 Micro SD card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Raspberry Pi Zero running Jessie Lite finishes the boot messages in 4.9 seconds, and allows me to log in after 10 seconds.

Comment: I installed jessie lite on a slightly overclocked (800 Mhz) B recently and would concur with this.   There were some issues the first few times with it trying to work something out with the keyboard and/or locale but a few iterations of `raspi-config` seemed to solve that.

Comment: would you mind posting how you were able to accomplish such a quick boot time? Even when I use my Pi 3, I don't get times like this. I have to edit the cmdline.txt in order to get this type of result

Comment: @BrettReinhard Using Jessie Lite, disabling wait for LAN and disabling boot to desktop.